# Part of speech 'as good'

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

'It must not be imagined that a walking tour is merely a better way of seeing the country. There are many ways of seeing landscape quite **as good**'

What part of speech is 'as good'?

Comment: It's old-fashioned prose, where the adjective phrase "as good" is being used adverbially to modify the VP "seeing landscape". In modern Standard English we would say "as well", though informally we often hear examples like "My car is not running too good", "I didn't play too good today".

Comment: @BillJ I dispute that _as good_ is old-fashioned. Walking is _a good way_ of seeing landscape, but there are other ways as (equally) good. The adjective _good_ modifies _ways_, not _seeing_.

Comment: Quite as good/bad/hot/cold/fun - we're talking adjectives here.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No one said it wasn't an adjective, so your comment is pointless.

Comment: @BillJ I read the sentence as being mistyped and missing the phrase "that are". This would have turned the sentence into "There are many ways of seeing landscape _that are_ quite as good."

Comment: @BillJ I get a different reading from you there. To me the sentence just means: "There are many ways of seeing landscape which are quite as good as a walking tour".